# SDKs for smart fridges for home automation

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, lg, home-automation

Does any of the Smart fridges (like LG Thinq products or Samsung) have sdks, using which we can use to integrate it with some home automation product?

Answer (score 0):

LG Developer website only offers SDKs for their smart TVs and smartphones.
http://developer.lge.com/gettingStarted/introduction/RetrieveDevelopmentOverview.dev

Samsung also only offers publicly available SDKs for their TVs and Galaxy devices only:
http://developer.samsung.com/home.do

So I guess the answer is no such public API available.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Home Appliances have APIs to do that but it still not fully public for controlling the device, commonly only for monitoring the status. See following link below for more information:

[Smart TV to Smart Home] http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/d54/index.html

Comment: thanks krisna. I checked that link before but I guess this cannot be used on other apps. I came across this video and was thinking it would be cool if can can ping this fridge and can get the fridge inventory by any external app.

Video - http://www.cnet.com/videos/how-to-use-samsungs-smart-fridge-to-help-manage-your-food-inventory/